# staying connected to facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I am currently developing in social engine in zend framework.
Social engine has this built in plugin that let you stay connected to facebook even you are logged out to facebook site. So when you're posting status in my social engine site, it will still be posted on your wall even you're not logged in facebook site(I mean here in facebook.com) but I don't know how to do this in my custom widget in social engine that's why I thought I should just use the Facebook SDK.

I was successful using Facebook SDK but the problem is that it asks the user to login every time the script detects that the user is not logged in facebook.com .
How to solve this??

I can actually retrieve the user details like openid, facebookemail. Yeps, that's only the thing I know :(

Answer (score 1):

I've developed same kind of application in Zend-Framework. I've used Facebook/PHP-SDK with oAuth 2.0.

In this case you need to save access tocken in your database for the particular user. and with that access token you can get any data as well as post to. Yes for that you need to grant necessary permission from the user for your Facebook APP.

Here is the two function that I've used in my application to fetch the access token , extended it and store in the database.

```
 /**
     * Getting User Acess Tocken , extended it and save it in to database......
     */
    public function getAccessToken($user_id,$fb_account_id)
    {
         $access_token=$this->facebook->getAccessToken();               
         $extended_access_token=$this->getExtendedAccessToken($access_token);                
        /** 
         * To save Access tocken and other necessary option
         */  
        $usr_bus_model = new Application_Model_UserBusinessAccounts;

        $usr_bus_model->loadAccount($user_id,'Facebook',(int)$fb_account_id);

        $usr_bus_model->details=$extended_access_token;
        $usr_bus_model->save();

        return $extended_access_token;
    }

     /**
     * Exrending User Acess Tocken.....
     */

    public function getExtendedAccessToken($access_token)
    {       

        $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";
        $params=array('client_id'=>self :: appId,'client_secret'=>self :: appSecretId,'grant_type'=>'fb_exchange_token','fb_exchange_token'=>$access_token);

          $response = $this->curl($token_url,$params);
          $response = explode ('=',$response);
          $response = explode ('&',$response[1]);
          $response = $response[0];       
          return $response;

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i've found a database table for facebook which may store the token (for offline access). did you use this kind of method?? after storing the offline access token, does it expire? or don't expire forever??

Comment: I've fetched access token via getAccessToken() - Facebook Object. And yes the offline_access permission will be removed in october so better you use this facebook object. And there is simple way to extended this access token for next 60 days. so when your user click to show the stream you can explicitely extended that particular user's access token. For your help I'll edit the post and put two function how I've fetched access token and extended acess token and store in database.